# IE8 fails at displaying the page completly

Tags: internet-explorer, http, rendering, xhtml-1.1

When I open [my project](http://thomtrack.veluwscollege.net/), Only the background and a image not found item are shown, while the page is 100% xhtml 1.1 strict. The developer tools show IE stops rendering after the SVG logo... Firefox works as it should. Damn You IE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not self-closing the 'object' tag.

```
<object data="/images/Logo_header.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

instead of

```
<object data="/images/Logo_header.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

Not sure if this is a bug though, or FF recovers gracefully. It is only valid XML if you also serve your page as XML, which you don't. You use 'text/html' instead of 'application/xhtml+xml'.

Comment: FF is not recovering as such: there is an Accept-Header-sniffer on the site which is serving it the same file as `application/xhtml+xml` instead of `text/html`, allowing Firefox to use a real XML parser which understands the self-closing tag.

Comment: Thats right: I've got detection in place that should find out based on headers wheter it should send as application/xhtml+xml. Firefox gets served as such. I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

Kamiel is right: you can't use an XML self-closing tag on IE. In any case, since IE can't render SVG, you will need to include some fallback content such as an image inside the object anyway.

I would advise against the sniff-and-serve-XHTML-as-XML-or-HTML approach you are using at the moment. There is no benefit to it; you will only get weird compatibility problems like this as your documents are handled with different parsing, style and DOM contexts. What's more, the `Vary: Accept` header you have to use in the response when you're doing this makes caching much less effective in IE. In any case, W3 [specifically don't allow](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/NOTE-xhtml-media-types-20020801/) XHTML-as-text/html for XHTML 1.1 documents.

Either go all-out and serve only XHTML 1.1 (sacrificing IE compatibility), or stick to serving XHTML 1.0 Strict content as text/html to all comers, observing [compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, It is really enlightening. 
But I'm still keeping this functionality in place, otherwise IE goes completly haywire. I'm aiming for a firefox audience anyway, it would just be nice if IE at least displayed a bit.